Mariabackup incremental backup and prepare process
I want to start using Mariabackup to backup a fairly large MariaDB database (v 10.6, 250GB) - current backup is taken using VMWare snapshots but they are crash consistent.
So far I have taken a weekly full backup and then a daily incremental for the last 5 days (I need to get to a 4 hour RPO as that is what is in the customer SLA but am going to work back from here). I am trying to find the "right" process to minimise load on the system contrasted with the time to restore should it be necessary.
I am aware that before being able to restore you need to complete the prepare process to ensure consistency. With my full backup which took just over 16 minutes to complete, the prepare process itself took 89 minutes. The system load was not huge but this was done at 2am with minimal usage by customers and am concerned if I run this at 2pm, the impact will be much greater.
My first thought in terms of a process was:
Weekly full - prepare immediately so restore time is minimised
Incremental 1 - apply to full and prepare immediately so restore time is minimised
Etc
That would mean if ever I need to restore, I always have the most recent backup already prepared and therefore the time etc is minimal when time is most critical.
However, I also have read on Percona forum a message from Percona staff member which says "the benefit of doing the prepare phase right after the backup finishes is that restore will be faster. You simply move back the files and start MariaDB. However you lose the ability to apply incremental backups on top of the full backup."
I have not seen anything regarding this on the MariaDB website so am trying to get my head around the best process to follow for this.
I have even looked for commercial backup software and am strugging - Zmanda looked promising but they have basically said that for MariaDB I would have to use Percona/Mariabackup anyways so they just become a scheduling engine really (albeit not a very expensive one).
What is the best way to hot backup a MariaDB database to achieve a 4 hour RPO with minimal impact on server/database load whilst also minimising the amount of time to do restores?
